# Selenium ReadTimeout error while logging in

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Building my very first test with Selenium + Ruby. There is a step where I have to log in.
I am passing login and password, then the script clicks "Log in" button.

The login process may take a while (system specifics - it's constantly like that and ok). So, while my script is waiting to log in, after ~100 seconds my code breaks into the error:
`` /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@2.5/2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/protocol.rb:181:in `rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout) ``

I assume I need to set up something like a `timeout` timing up to 240 sec for example but can't find the right way of doing that.

Could you help me to set up a right timeout property, please?

Thank you!

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'


driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
# driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 240 - Tried it, didn't help
# driver.manage.timeouts.page_load = 240 - 

driver.navigate.to 'https://webiste.com'

#Entering my login and password
driver.find_element(id: 'admin_user_email').send_keys('MY_LOGIN')
driver.find_element(id: 'admin_user_password').send_keys('MY_PASSWORD')

#Clicking Login button and at this step my script breaks after ~100 sec
driver.find_element(id: 'admin_user_submit_action').click

driver.navigate.to 'https://another_URL_after_logged_in'

puts 'You are on the page'
```

Comment: Are you running locally or in a container?

Comment: I run it locally now

Comment: Are you getting locally the same error?

Comment: Yeah, I am running this code from my local machine and get this error. I am trying to find a way to increase the TimeOut in the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As asked for in the comments. The timeout can be increased by doing this:

```rb
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.timeout = 240 # Or whatever you need
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :http_client => client
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you! Could you advice please, why you asked where I run it? What will be the difference?
Or if it is a long topic, maybe you can tell me what I need to learn? Thanks :)

Comment: It is a short one. The error that you see is consistent with a "false" error when running in containers. If a container does not have big enough shm (shared memory space) it will throw the same error, misleading people into fixing problem that does not exist.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Will note it for the future